# Result of an empty date input tag in PHP

Tags: php, forms, null

I'm crashing my head on a wall, seriously, but seems i've problem with input tag type="date", when I DO NOT insert any date leaving the field like this:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE9q4.png)

This the input field:

```
<input class="w-100 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold rounded 
border-danger" name="data_finale_abbonamento" id="data_finale_abbonamento" 
type="date" value="<?=$data_finale_abbonamento;?>" style="font-size:10px">
```

and that's the part where I try to put value in mysql Database.

```
if (isset($_POST['data_finale_abbonamento'])) {
$data_finale_abbonamento = $_POST["data_finale_abbonamento"];
} 

$sql_edit_cliente="update clienti set 
piva = '$piva', n_ragsoc = UPPER('$n_ragsoc'), 
referente = UPPER('$referente'), 
cellulare = '$cellulare', 
mail_referente = UPPER('$mail_referente'), 
userpass = '$userpass', 
comune = UPPER('$comune'), 
regione = UPPER('$regione'), 
responsabilita = UPPER('$responsabilita'), 
abbonamento = ($abbonamento), 
tipo_abbo = ($tipoabbo), 
data_iniziale_abbonamento = ('$data_iniziale_abbonamento'), 
data_finale_abbonamento = ('$data_finale_abbonamento') 
where 
clienti.id_clienti = '$id_cliente'";            
mysqli_query($con, $sql_edit_cliente)or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

So, I'm not able to intercept the result of this field cause it seems NOT NULL and is responding to an ISSET behaviour, but, what's the value ?

I tried to intercept it with blank space " ", or with "", but i'm not lucky. Am I forgetting something ?

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the problem without seeing the relevant code.  Please edit your question so we can see exactly how you're handling this form input

Comment: I dont think the problems depends on code, query is working perfectly, but the date field is always recognized as ISSET. So that means is never null, even if I delete the content, leaving the simple DD/MM/YYYY as in photo. And in that case, it gives me an error of invalid value.

Comment: Hmm... nothing is jumping out at me (aside from the fact that you should be using prepared statements for your database queries for security and formatting reasons (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).  Have you tried debugging the variable, either through your IDE or the old fashioned way by echoing the contents of that variable to the screen at various points of your script?

Comment: already did it, nothing is printed out if I post the input field with no date inside.
The only thing I know is that if I put an echo inside the condition of $data_finale_abbonamento = $_POST["data_finale_abbonamento"], so the echo is printed. So this means is like the variable is set, but ... what's inside ??!?!?! :)

Comment: Well, if there's no value, then any echo would be blank.  And, thinking about it... is this your only SQL statement?  Because if so, then, yeah, you'd be inserting null values without a date set.  Or... am I misunderstanding what the problem actually is?

Comment: I need to know if the value is NULL or EMPTY to put NULL inside the query.
Or to put the variable itself value if is NOT NULL.

Maybe i've resolved with EMPTY check. The variable seems to be empty if I leave it with no values.

Comment: @FrancescoMinniti can you post a `var_dump($_POST[])`? at your script? just to make sure what date coming in. Also post DB data map of the fields.

Comment: It might be different format of the `date`, what you trying to insert in to the DB.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['data_finale_abbonamento'], $data_finale_abbonamento)` gives what?

Comment: I tried var_dump($_POST['data_finale_abbonamento']); No result. Nothing printed.

Comment: So, in other words, you just need: `if (!isset($_POST['date'])) { $date = null; } else { $date = $_POST['date']; }` ?  Written out, check to see if the input is set.  If not, assign null to the variable you're using to populate your DB.  Otherwise just assign the input's value to that same variable

Comment: That's it .. but ISSETis not the right answer. Cause if I use it, It tells me the variable is always set, even if the date is not set in the form field.I resolved with EMPTY.
if (!empty($_POST['date'])) { $date = null; } else { $date = $_POST['date']; }